How to Create a Windows Executable with Electron Forge that Adds a Desktop Shortcut?
I'm working on an Electron app and using electron-forge to build the executable file. My goal is to create an installer that behaves like a typical Windows installer, including creating an app icon/shortcut on the desktop after installation.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Installed electron-forge and set up my project
Ran the command npm run make, which successfully creates the .exe file
Used the @electron-forge/maker-squirrel package as my maker
The problem is that when I run the installer, it installs the app, but no shortcut is created on the desktop. The app runs fine, but I need it to also create a desktop icon.
Here's part of my package.json related to the maker:
"config": {
   "forge": {
   "packagerConfig": {},
   "makers": [
        {
         "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
         "config": {
         "name": "my_app",
         "setupIcon": "./assets/icon.ico", // Optional, to set a custom installer icon
         "iconUrl": "https://yourwebsite.com/icon.ico", // URL to the icon for the app
         "shortcutName": "MyApp", // Set the shortcut name
         "createDesktopShortcut": true, // Create a desktop shortcut
         "createStartMenuShortcut": true // Optionally create a start menu shortcut
        }
      }
    ]
   }
 }

What should I change or add to ensure the installer creates a desktop shortcut? Do I need to configure something additional for the Squirrel installer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Trying get execute able file for Mac and Linuxyour text

I have also ran into some issues with electron-forge.
After doing some research - here is what helped.
Solving your problem:
In your src/app/electron/main.ts add to createWindow():
function createWindow() {
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) app.quit();

For whatever reason this helps with creating the shortcut app icon.
Plus it supresses the unnecessary two-time startup within the installation process.
Helpful sidenote:
In the installation process, electron forge uses its default-gif.

electron_squirrel_default_spinner

You can replace that, by just adding loadingGif to the forge.config.ts:
makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        name: 'appname',
        icon: './src/assets/fav.ico',
        setupIcon: './src/assets/fav.ico',
        loadingGif: './src/assets/splash.gif'
      }
    }

With this setup I did not encounter any issues. Hope it helped.
